# How to customize query loop block with a search string from the query parameters

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm running WordPress 6.0.1 and I'd like to achieve a smilingly easy thing, I have a query loop which shows posts that must be filtered by a query parameter so I can add a search box into the page.

I tried passing URL parameters like '?s=keyword_to_search_for' but it doesn't seem to be affected so I enabled the option "Inherit query from template" where the results should be affected by the global query configuration. My issue is that when that's enabled no posts are shown (while when it's disabled it shows all).

The query loop shows all my posts correctly with the pagination, I just want to put a search box above the list to be able to filter them through URL parameters.

[image: Query Loop]

[image: Query Loop Settings]

Comment: Also posted here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/407888/how-to-filter-query-loop-block-with-a-search-string-from-the-query-parameters

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar requirement to alter the search parameter of the `core/search` and found a [block variation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-variations/) to be the easiest way, as the query is an attribute of the block.

**JavaScript**

```js
// Register a custom search block variation for "keyword_to_search_for"
wp.blocks.registerBlockVariation('core/search',
    {
        name: 'custom-search',
        title: 'Custom Search',
        attributes: {
            query: { s: 'keyword_to_search_for' }
        },
        scope: ['block', 'inserter', 'transform']
    }
);
```

Once you have registered the custom search variation, use it in place of the default search block.

The resulting markup saved from the custom search block variation is:

```html
<!-- wp:search {"query":{"s":"keyword_to_search_for"}} /-->
```

Alternatively, you could just use the above markup in your Query loop if you don't need/want to register a block variation. When the search is used on the frontend, the resulting search string is `?s=text&s=keyword_to_search_for` where `text` is the free text entered in the search box with `keyword_to_search_for` appended.